# Error after trying to change activity after specified time - "Unfortunately, Application has stopped"

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm totally green in android programming. I just wanted to make a "splash" screen, which will change after few seconds to main activity. That's code I have used:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diavlo_font);  
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "DiavloBlack-Regular.ttf");  
    txt.setTypeface(font);  

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        //Do something after time
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);
      }
    }, 5000);

}
```

I'm pretty sure, that the problem is when I'm trying to call another activity. In fact, I used it only "after pressing button", but now I can't make it run :/
Sorry, maybe this is stupid and easy thing, but I have been trying to solve this problem for few days and unfortunately I found nothing. 
Will be very grateful for any tips how to solve it.
PS sorry for my English :)

Edit:
Sorry for not adding logs, hope they are those right.

```
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start        activity ComponentInfo{com.example.czolgi.ii.ws/com.example.czolgi.ii.ws.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at com.example.czolgi.ii.ws.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:15)
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
09-20 17:49:10.740: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  ... 11 more
```

Adding SecondActivity:

```
package com.example.czolgi.ii.ws;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_second, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**SULUTION:**

So the solution of this problem is just add // before getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
or simply erese it. The second activity didn't work because i tried to display action bar with set "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen". So I only must delete those line or change style to not full screen.

Comment: Im not sure what u mean by "stacktrace", but i have attached logcat.

Comment: Post the onCreate() of your second activity. The problem is in it.

Comment: Which device/emulator are you testing it on?

Comment: Emulator: Android 4.1
Device: Samsung Galaxy S + (4.0.4)

Comment: Ok, now everythings work fine, as I thought it was probably only my little, stupid mistake -,-

Comment: @MaciejSalamon Please post what your solution was so that anyone with a similar problem in the future can use it.

Comment: So the solution of this problem is just add // before getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
or simply erese it. The second activity didn't work because i tried to display action bar with set "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen". So I only must delete those line or change style to not full screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is on the following line:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

My guess is that you are trying to run your app on an Android version in which the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) doesn't exist, that is below API 11.

You could also try adding the following to your onCreate(), before you try to getActionBar():

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

If it still doesn't work, the theme your app is using does not have an ActionBar in it. There's this huge blogpost on how to identify and fix this problem [here](http://blog.perpetumdesign.com/2011/08/strange-case-of-dr-action-and-mr-bar.html).

If you want to use the ActionBar in your app below Honeycomb (API 11), then you should consider using the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), which can provide this functionality.

Comment: Omg, really THANK YOU! Just eresed getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
and everything is working now. But im using 4.0.4 and higher?

Comment: @MaciejSalamon i've updated my answer with two possible fixes. If those don't work, I have no idea

Comment: OK, I'm probably just idiot, because I have set android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" to ALL aplication... This is the most problably thing, that caused all thouse errors. Ok, will try to set a normal theme to SecondActivity and write if it work. 
Again great thx!